# Is there a way to locate/detect streaks of data from several columns at the same time in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I've been trying for a while to come up with a code that calculates streaks from several columns at the same time, for a table where i need to find streaks of values that are above 0. At first, i managed to use a formula that shows the rungroup, the column indicating the number of data that differs the one in question at its respective row. As shown bellow:

```
select descrip, 
`1.01`, 
(select count(*) 
    from `all_data` dp
        where dp.`1.01` <> dpo.`1.01`
        and dp.descrip <= dpo.descrip) as rungroup,
`1.02`,
(select count(*)
    from `all_data` dp
        where dp.`1.02` <> dpo.`1.02`
        and dp.descrip <= dpo.descrip) as rungroup_2

from `all_data` dpo;
```

1.01 and 1.02 are the name of the columns, and descrip is used to ordenate the data. This model works so far, but i don't know how couls i use it within another query to show streaks from both columns. Would there be a way for such?

Answer (score 0):

You should for sure make an `UNION` query with your 2 columns.

Something like this

```
SELECT descrip, thecol,
      (select count(*)
       from `all_data` dp
       where (dp.`1.01` <> dpo.thecol AND dp.`1.02` <> dpo.thecol)
         and dp.descrip <= dpo.descrip) as rungroup
FROM
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM
    (
        SELECT '1.01' AS origcol, descrip, `1.01` AS thecol from `all_data`
        UNION ALL
        SELECT '1.02' AS origcol, descrip, `1.02` AS thecol from `all_data`
    )
    ORDER BY descrip, thecol
) dpo;
```

However I am totally unsure about this part :

```
where (dp.`1.01` <> dpo.thecol AND dp.`1.02` <> dpo.thecol)
```

it might be an `OR` instead of an `AND`. It is not easy without seeing the data.

Just play around with my query, decompose to get only the UNION subquery, fix... and you'll get it.

Comment: This code is suppoded to go within another code, Try calling it 'SQL1' and see if it makes sence within the next code: 
SELECT Result, MIN(descrip) as StartDate, MAX(descrip) as EndDate, COUNT(*) as `months` FROM (SQL 1) A GROUP BY `1.01`, RunGroup ORDER BY Min(descrip);.
Sorry if it gets confusing for you. It is intended to work with one column and i'm trying to make it work with several

Comment: I don't understand anything:-) comments are not suited for this, I suggest that you edit your question to add this information in a clear way.

Comment: I got the explanation that gave me the lead to this code here.
http://www.sqlteam.com/article/detecting-runs-or-streaks-in-your-data
 That was my starting point.